# Powershell 2.0 - Invoke-wmimethod and get the computer name in gridview

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wmi, powershell-2.0, msgbox

I have a powershell script/gui that i want to use to broadcast a message to all ActiveDirectory computers.The message does get broadcasted to all workstations but I want to get the computer name(as output) before the invoke-wmimthod runs for each computer through grid-view if possible.

```
function BroadcastMulti{
Import-Module active*

try{
    $msg = read-host "Enter your message "
    $List = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "PC*"}  | Select -ExpandName 
    Invoke-WmiMethod -Path Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "msg /time:3600 * $msg" -ComputerName $List
}catch{
     [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Input was not entered correctly")
}
}
}
```

Comment: Just add `| Out-GridView -PassThru -OutputMode Multiple` after `Select-Object`

Comment: Did you mean after the "Select -expandName" ?

Should i change "Select -expandName" to "Select-Object -expandName" ?

Comment: As a best practice in scripts, you shouldn't use aliases (`select` is an alias for `Select-Object` and I believe you mean `-ExpandProperty` as `-ExpandName` is not a parameter unless that's a typo for `-Expand Name` which is another form of alias for the `-ExpandProperty` parameter).

Comment: Unfortunately the command you had recommended did not work and my catch parameter caught it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function BroadcastMulti{
    Import-Module active* 
    try{
        $msg = read-host "Enter your message "
        $List = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "Computer*"}  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 

        foreach($_ in $list){
        Write-Host $_
        $_ | Out-File C:\SupportTools\BroadcastReport.txt -Append
        Invoke-WmiMethod -Path Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "msg /time:43200 * $msg" -ComputerName $_
        }
        #[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Message sent to all workstations")
    }catch{
         [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("There was an error, please try again")
          }
    }
```